# Does any word rhyme with 'wolf'?

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

I would like to know if there are rhyming words (perfect, identical or [holorhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holorime)) for the word *wolf.* Having searched online only for a short while, I believe there might be a word lurking about. *Gulf* doesn't quite cut it.

Comment: http://www.b-rhymes.com/rhyme/word/wolf

Comment: will "Golf" do? Despite the fact it is that very "Eye rhyme"  - it sounds (at least according to Google) well enough.

Comment: erm.... tasmanian wolf?

Comment: @Rossitten: "I played some golf beside a gulf/Until a wolf began to wulf."

Comment: @SvenYargs Lol nice one.

Comment: About that _other question_... are you actually asking if _rhymes_ exist in other languages, or are you asking for other-language words that rhyme with _wolf_?

Comment: Rhymes with 'wolf'. @oerkelens

Comment: As for an identical rhyme, you could use the _verb_ wolf, of course. But that may be a bit cheap :)

Comment: @SvenYargs For me *wolf* /wʊlf/ and *golf* /gɔlf/ have different rimes, at least in my language, while *wolve* /wʊlv/ is a verb so voices the final consonant. I think that in general an *L* before the consonant is unstable between speakers, so these rhymes are hard to come by; think how often (meaning, in how many speakers) *calm* /kɔlm/ and *palm* /pɔlm/ lose their phonemic /l/. There’s probably another way of writing that phonetically that uses a fancier vowel, but I don’t know it. However, I think the same thing happens with *wolf*; I just don’t know how to represent a quasi-phantom [l].

Comment: Just use "werewolf".  No need for Tasmanian wolf.

Comment: "Orange", obviously.

Comment: How can one possibly pronounce the English words "gulf" and "wolf" such that they aren't "perfect" rhymes? Consontant, "ul" as in "ulcer" or "old", f...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you're ***out of luck***:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_without_rhymes

Unless you can make do with
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wulf

> one of the most prolific elements in early Germanic names

Or
http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/words-that-rhyme-with/wolf.html

> wolfe, wolff, woolf, wulf, wulff

Personally, these attempts to make do just confirm the original "No".

Perhaps an alternative like ***"canine"*** can give you better perspective?

Comment: I'm good; I'm not using it in a poem, although I'm writing many at the moment... Thank you for the links!

The adjective word for wolf, I believe, is 'lupine'.
Thank you once again.

Comment: Heh. Good one. Those do rhyme.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are probably loads of holorimes. For example, if you were going to a wool shop, and wanted a different wool for each day of the week you might say:

- Do you have a wool for Friday?

... And if you were speaking to a large wolf-eating bear who only eats wolves on Fridays, you might say:

- Do you have a wolf a Friday?

.... in the sense of *Do you eat one wolf each Friday?*.

The phonemic script for these in Southern Standard British English is :

- /du ju 'hæv ə 'wʊl fə 'fraɪdeɪ/

and

- /du ju 'hæv ə 'wʊlf ə 'fraɪdeɪ/

Of course the gaps there are only a convention to make this type of transcription easy to read. What we actually say in both cases is:

- /duju'hævə'wʊlfə'fraɪdeɪ/

This might not work if you speak a rhotic  English like General American, for example, because the word *for* could still have an /r/ in it!

Comment: Americans are perfectly willing to delete the /r/ in *for* (unlike the /r/s in most words) when speaking fast.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider ***dolf***, defined [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dolf) as the imperative of "delve". According to the pronunciation at that site, it seems to rhyme with "wolf."

It is also listed [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dolf) as meaning "a despised person," although the pronunciation is unclear.

As for holorhymes, how about:

- *She has a wool fear*.
- *She has a wolf ear.*